# Принадлежность точки дуге

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

У меня есть окружность, известен радиус как R, известен центр окружности(xc, yc).

[image: ате]

Я рисую два вектора с центра к краю окружности. Как узнать, точка с координатами (x,y) находится между векторами или нет

Comment: -1 - Вам это нужно по картинке определить? Или все-таки есть какие-то входные данные?

Comment: Вас за семь лет не устроил ни один ответ на Ваши вопросы?

Comment: @Igor "Чего стоит услуга, которая уже оказана?" (с) С другой стороны, может, человек даже не подозревает, зачем возле ответов птичка :)

Comment: Нет Вы не "рисуете". Если только задача не заключается в анализе растрового изображения. Сейчас я Вам еще один минус поставлю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Определить углы радиусов, угол радиуса к точке и убедиться, что этот угол там, где надо угол :)

Основной вопрос - любая точка на окружности в принципе на этой дуге... Только одна дуга (на рисунке) - сверху, вторая - снизу :) Тут уж решайте сами, принадлежность какой дуге нужна...

**Update**

С учетом изменения условия в комментариях - находите угол между векторами (x-x0,y-y0) и (x1-x0,y1-y0) - из центра к вашей точке и к точке (x1,y1) - например, вычисляя скалярное произведение - и смотрите, меньше ли он указанного вами раствора (последнее ваше значение - 45 градусов).

Если меньше - попадает, если больше - нет...

Собственно, вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или даже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только тут неплохо бы убедиться, что расстояния от точек до центра и правда равны радиусу...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сори, исправил описание

Comment: Ну и что? Вы все равно не указали, как определяются ваши радиусы *"Я рисую два вектора с центра к краю окружности"*, а без этого - всегда можно нарисовать их так, что заранее определенная точка туда попадет...

Comment: У нас есть круг, у круга есть центр(он известен), известна точка(x,y), она находится в круге, я ставлю ещё одну точку(x1, y1) делаю ей -PI +PI(чтобы получился конус как на картинке) и мне нужно понять, попадает ли точка (x, y) в этот конус

Comment: Если вы к любой точке делаете +pi и -pi, то получаете 2*pi=360 градусов. Ответ - да, любая точка точно попадает в эту дугу...

Comment: это примерное значение(сори за некорректный пример), будет там около 90 градусов суммарно, +45 и - 45 градусов

Comment: См. исправленный (дополненный) ответ.

Comment: x0, y0 и x1,y1 - это два вектора? Может расшифровать что в вашей формуле означают переменные?

Comment: Центр окружности - (x0,y0). Точка M *на окружности* - (x,y). Сектор задается его срединной точкой (x1,y1) на окружности, при этом его размах - по углу φ в каждую сторону от (x1,y1). Так понятно? Вторая формула справедлива, если точки (x1,y1) и (x,y) лежат точно на окружности.

Comment: Примерный чертеж добавил в ответ.

Comment: супер, так лучше! спасибо! Как потом в итоге понять что точка принадлежит сектору? У нас есть фи, он должен быть одинаковый у двух векторов, да?

Comment: Аа, или же мне нужно сначала найти угол фи, потом посчитать по вашей формуле и сравнить результат формулы с фи?

Comment: Блин, ну вы же сами мне это писали, это ваша формулировка! *У нас есть круг, у круга есть центр(он известен), известна точка(x,y), она находится в круге, я ставлю ещё одну точку(x1, y1) делаю ей -PI +PI(чтобы получился конус как на картинке) и мне нужно понять, попадает ли точка (x, y) в этот конус* Как уж вы этот "конус" задаете - дело ваше!!

Answer (score 4):

Данный подход не использует тригонометрических функций и вообще углов, только векторная алгебра.

Задача так толком и не поставлена, но будем считать, что размер сектора не превышает Pi.

Векторы X1, X2 и A - из центра к первой точке, ко второй, и к точке a

```
x1 = p1.x - xc
y1 = p1.y - yc
x2 = p2.x - xc
y2 = p2.y - yc
xa = a.x - xc
ya = a.y - yc
```

Тогда посчитаем знаки (-1; 0; +1) косых произведений векторов `X1 x X2`, `X1 x A`, `A x X2`.

```
s12 = sign(x1*y2 - y1*x2)
s1a = sign(x1*ya - y1*xa)
sa2 = sign(xa*y2 - ya*x2)
```

Если все три знака совпадают (или среди них есть нули), то точка А находится в секторе X1X2 независимо от взаимной ориентации X1 и X2

Comment: Расшифруйте пожалуйста. переменные вашей формулы

Comment: Да пожалуйста .